# CQ5 author. hyperlinks are getting shortened

Tags: hyperlink, url-rewriting, aem, configuration-files, author

In author environment in CQ5, there exists many hyperlinks on a page.
For example:
"login account". I have given the path "www.example.com/content/sites/us/en/home/accounts/login.html". But when i hit the hyperlink the it is getting redirected to "www.example.com/accounts/login.html" and it is giving not found error.
Even in preview mode when i inspect element the hyperlink then also it is showing the shortened URL. Please help

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: what do you see when you go to "/system/console/jcrresolver" on that serverand  use the map  option on the configuration tester for  "/content/sites/us/en/home/accounts/login".